# API call handling in offline mode (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-saga, redux-offline

Is there a way to handle an API call which was sent while being online but all of a sudden after that call is made you lost network and got in offline mode meaning that the request has been sent to the server but you won't be able to see the response due to being in offline mode.

Also, being in offline mode if I make an API call (putting it in offline queue) to update some field of a particular record and before getting back online some other user (in online mode) made an update call for that particular record then how can such a case in offline mode be handled which requires synchronization ?

Do libraries like `redux-offline` and `react-native-offline` handle such scenarios ?